# Measure as a dual of $C_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a nonnegative finite measure on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n,$ i.e. $\mu(\Omega) < \infty.$

Clearly for any $f \in C_0(\Omega)$ we have $\int\limits_{\Omega}fd{\mu} \leq ||f||_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} \mu(\Omega).$ Do we also have the following?

\begin{equation}
\mu(\Omega)= \sup\limits_{ f\in C_0(\Omega), ||f||_{L^{\infty}}=1 }  \int \limits_{\Omega} f d \mu.
\end{equation}

More generally for a signed measure $\mu$ on $\Omega\subset{\mathbb{R}^N}$  (bounded subset), do we have

$|\mu|(\Omega)=||\mu||_{\Omega},$ where $||.||_{\Omega}$ dentes the norm on $\mathcal{M}(\Omega)$ as a dual of $C_0(\Omega)?$

Answer (score 1):

For a nonnegative measure $\mu$  consider $f_k(x)=e^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots +x_n^2)/k^2}.$ Clearly $f_k\in C_0(\Omega)$ and $0\le f_k\le 1.$ Then by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem we get
$$\lim_k\int\limits_{\Omega}f_k(x)\,d\mu(x)=\int\limits_{\Omega}\,d\mu(x)=\mu(\Omega)$$
Therefore
$$\sup_{f\in C_0(\Omega),\ 0\le f\le 1}\int\limits_{\Omega} f\,d\mu\ge \mu(\Omega)$$
The reverse inequality is obvious.

For a signed measure $\mu$ we have decompositions $\Omega=\Omega_1\cup\Omega_2$ and $\mu=\mu_1-\mu_2$ such that $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are positive measures and $\mu_1(\Omega_2)=\mu_2(\Omega_1)=0.$
Now the problem is to approximate the function ${\bf 1}_{\Omega_1}-{\bf 1}_{\Omega_2}$ by continuous functions $f_k$ so that $\|f_k\|_\infty \le 1.$ The details can be found in textbooks in real analysis (Royden or Rudin).

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that $\mu$ is a *regular Borel* measure.

The result you're trying to prove is part of the statement of the Riesz representation theorem. However, in my answer, I'll derive your result by more elementary means, without appealing to the Riesz representation theorem.

I'll first deal with the case where $\mu$ is a positive finite measure, though in an edit below, I'll cover the signed case too.

Since $\mu$ is regular by assumption, we can say that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a compact subset $K \subset \Omega $ such that $\mu(K) > \mu(\Omega) - \epsilon$.

By Urysohn's lemma, there exists an $f \in C_c(\Omega)$ with $0 \leq f \leq 1$ such that $f = 1$ on $K$.

Then
$$   \int f d\mu \geq \mu(K) > \mu(\Omega) - \epsilon $$

Thus
$$ \sup_{f \in C_c(\Omega), |f| \leq 1} \left| \int f d\mu \right| > \mu(\Omega) - \epsilon$$
for all $\epsilon > 0$, which implies that
$$ \sup_{f \in C_c(\Omega), |f| \leq 1} \left| \int f d\mu \right| \geq \mu(\Omega)$$

Since $C_c(\Omega) \subset C_0(\Omega)$, we also have
$$ \sup_{f \in C_0(\Omega), |f| \leq 1} \left| \int f d\mu \right| \geq \mu(\Omega)$$

The reverse inequality is obvious, as you have pointed out.

---

**Edit:** I'll also cover the case where $\mu$ is a signed measure.

As Ryszard Szwarc points out, the Hahn decomposition gives us disjoint Borel subsets $\Sigma^+$ and $\Sigma^-$ such that $\mu^+$ is supported on $\Sigma^+$ and $\mu^-$ is supported on $\Sigma^-$.

By assumption, $\mu$ is regular, which is equivalent to saying that
$\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ are both regular. So given an $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a compact subset $K^+ \subset \Sigma^+  $ such that $\mu^+(K^+) > \mu^+(\Sigma^+) - \epsilon$; there also exists a compact subset $K^- \subset \Sigma^- $ such that $\mu^-(K^-) > \mu^-(\Sigma^-) - \epsilon$.

Define the open sets $U^+ = \Omega \setminus K^-$ and $U^- = \Omega \setminus K^+$. We have $U^+ \supset \Sigma^+$ and $U^- \supset \Sigma^-$, and we have $\mu^-(U^+) < \epsilon$ and $\mu^+(U^-) < \epsilon$.

By Urysohn's lemma, we can find an $f^+ \in C_c(\Omega)$ with $0 \leq f^+ \leq 1$, with $f^+ = 1$ on $K^+$ and with support contained in $U^+$ . Similarly, we can find an $f^- \in C_c(\Omega)$ with $0 \leq f^- \leq 1$, with $f^- = 1$ on $K^-$ and with support contained in $U^-$.

Now observe that
$$ \int f^+ d\mu^+ \geq \mu^+(K^+) > \mu^+(\Sigma^+) - \epsilon $$
$$ \int f^+ d\mu^- \leq \mu^-(U^+) < \epsilon $$
$$ \int f^- d\mu^- \geq \mu^-(K^-) > \mu^-(\Sigma^-) - \epsilon $$
$$ \int f^- d\mu^+ \leq \mu^+(U^-) < \epsilon $$

So if we define $f = f^+ - f^-$, we have $|f| \leq 1$ and
\begin{align*}
\int f d\mu & = \int f^+ d\mu^+ - \int f^+ d\mu^-  + \int f^- d\mu^- - \int f^- d\mu^+  \\
& > \mu^+(\Sigma^+) + \mu(\Sigma^-) - 4\epsilon \\
& = |\mu|(\Omega) - 4\epsilon
\end{align*}

The rest of the argument proceeds as before.

Comment: The asker is after $$\sup_{f\in C_0(\Omega),|f|\le 1}\left |\int f\,d\mu\right |\ge |\mu|(\Omega)$$ which is different from the last formula in your answer.

Comment: Good point. I'll edit this, answering for the case where $\mu$ is a positive measure. Your point about the Hahn decomposition covers the case of the signed measure.